# rotate image downloaded from api on hover/mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am downloading data from pokeapi.co and dynamically adding them to the table. There are some statistics and an image. I would like that image to rotate on hover. (I dynamically added an id="pokeImage" while creating the table.) I tried to do that in CSS:

```
 #pokeImage:hover {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg);}
```

and in jQuery:

```
$('#pokeImage').on('click', function () { 
$(this).css({ 
    transform: 'rotate(' + (Math.random()*45+45).toFixed(3) + 'deg)'
});
```

But it didn't work.
Do You have any advice how to do that ?
Thank you

EDIT this is how I get data, put it in a table and displaying it

```
$('#getPokemons').click(function(){
var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.className = "table table-condensed";
        table.setAttribute("id", "ajaxTable");

        var header = document.createElement('tr');
        header.innerHTML = '<th> Name </th><th> Image </th><th> HP </th>';
        header.setAttribute("id", "tableHeader");
        table.appendChild(header);

var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
for(var i = random ; i <= random + 10; i++){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+i+"/",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        var name = response.forms[0].name;
        var imgUrl = response.sprites.front_default;
        var hpName = response.stats[5].stat.name ; 
        var hpVal= response.stats[5].base_stat;

        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = '<td>' + name + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<img id="pokeImage" src ="'+imgUrl+'"/>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + hpVal + '</td>';
        $('#pokedex1').append(row);

    }
});}    $('#pokedex1').append(table);});
```

Comment: If you need rotating on mouseover, you need to use mouseover event then, but you are using click. Is it not working even when you clicking on the image?

Comment: It is not working on click either...I was just trying different function to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below snippet its working on mouseover event

```js
$('#pokeImage').on('mouseover', function () { 
   $(this).css({ 
      transform: 'rotate(' + (Math.random()*45+45).toFixed(3) + 'deg)'
   }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="pokeImage" src= "http://images.indianexpress.com/2017/06/oneplus5_final_image.jpg">
```

**Updated code snippet**

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="getPokemons" value="submit">Click</button>
<div id="pokedex1"></div>
<script>
$('#getPokemons').click(function(){
 var table = document.createElement('table');
 table.className = "table table-condensed";
 table.setAttribute("id", "ajaxTable");

 var header = document.createElement('tr');
 header.innerHTML = '<th> Name </th><th> Image </th><th> HP </th>';
 header.setAttribute("id", "tableHeader");
 table.appendChild(header);

 var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
 for(var i = random ; i <= random + 10; i++){
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+i+"/",
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response){
    var name = response.forms[0].name;
    var imgUrl = response.sprites.front_default;
    var hpName = response.stats[5].stat.name ; 
    var hpVal= response.stats[5].base_stat;

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = '<td>' + name + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<img id="pokeImage" src ="'+imgUrl+'" onmouseover = "rotateImage(event)"/>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + hpVal + '</td>';
    $('#pokedex1').append(row);
   }
  });
 }    
 $('#pokedex1').append(table);
});
function rotateImage(event) {
 $(event.target).css('transform', 'rotate(' +  (Math.random()*45+45).toFixed(3) + 'deg)');
}
</script>
</html>
```

**mouseout event added**

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="getPokemons" value="submit">Click</button>
<div id="pokedex1"></div>
<script>
$('#getPokemons').click(function(){
 var table = document.createElement('table');
 table.className = "table table-condensed";
 table.setAttribute("id", "ajaxTable");

 var header = document.createElement('tr');
 header.innerHTML = '<th> Name </th><th> Image </th><th> HP </th>';
 header.setAttribute("id", "tableHeader");
 table.appendChild(header);

 var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
 for(var i = random ; i <= random + 10; i++){
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+i+"/",
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response){
    var name = response.forms[0].name;
    var imgUrl = response.sprites.front_default;
    var hpName = response.stats[5].stat.name ; 
    var hpVal= response.stats[5].base_stat;

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = '<td>' + name + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<img id="pokeImage" src ="'+imgUrl+'" />' + '</td>' + '<td>' + hpVal + '</td>';
    $(document).on("mouseover", "#pokeImage", rotateImage);
    $(document).on("mouseout", "#pokeImage", reRotateImage);
    $('#pokedex1').append(row);
   }
  });
 }    
 $('#pokedex1').append(table);
});
function rotateImage(event) {
 $(event.target).css('transform', 'rotate(' + 355 + 'deg)');
}
function reRotateImage(event) {
 $(event.target).css('transform', 'rotate(' + 0 + 'deg)');
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you getting any errors?. Update your question or provide fiddle so that i can help you.

Comment: Thanks ! It is moving now :)  
I have one more question - how should I change 
('transform', 'rotate(' +  (Math.random()*45+45).toFixed(3) + 'deg)')
if I want it to always rotate 360deg and then rotate it back when not hovering ?

Comment: I'll provide you new snippet soon.

Comment: checkout the last snippet.

Comment: It looks like its rotating only about 5deg. I am actually trying to "find" appropriate amount of deg to rotate it all the way around.
The rotate back fuction works ! 
Thank you very much ! You've been very helpful ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help. Even without js rotation is working.

```css
.someImage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.someImage:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="someImage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax for the .css selector. It's `.css( propertyName, value )`, as described in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

In your case, you should use.

```
$(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + (Math.random()*45+45).toFixed(3) + 'deg)'));
```

See below snippet for a working example.

```js
$('#pokeImage').on('mouseover', function () { 
  $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' +  (Math.random()*45+45).toFixed(3) + 'deg)');
}); 

// Optionally, to rotate it back when not hovering
$('#pokeImage').on('mouseout', function () { 
  $(this).css(
    'transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="pokeImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x70">
```

Also, if adding elements dynamically (like through an AJAX request), you need to add the event handler dynamically as well. Try this:

```
 /* ... */

var row = document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML = '<td>' + name + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<img id="pokeImage" src ="'+imgUrl+'"/>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + hpVal + '</td>';

$(row).on('mouseout', function () { 
  $(this).css(
    'transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
});

$('#pokedex1').append(row);

/* ... */
```

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately I didn't work :(

Comment: @Keira09 Can you share some more context, with some surrounding code? This code is working in the snippet, so it should be working for you as well.

Comment: When adding content dynamically event handlers need to be added dynamically as well. I updated my answer, see if that works!

Comment: Unforunately it does not... and I do not get any errors